# How to filter a OneToMany field using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, one-to-many

I'm trying to filter out posts associated with a category depending on whether the post is set as hidden or not.

I can do this with a post-query filter just fine (see below) but I was wondering if it's possible to construct the query using the JPA methods? (Specifically the query building methods like FindAllBy..., I'm hoping to keep database agnostic by sticking to these types of queries)

I could also probably call FindAllByCategory on the PostRepository and construct the return that way but it feels hacky and backwards.

So to summarize I'd like to find a way to declare FindAllAndFilterPostsByIsHidden(boolean isHidden)

Category Class

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    public Category(String name, Post... posts) {
        this.name = name;
        this.posts = Stream.of(posts)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.posts.forEach(post -> post.setCategory(this));
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Post> posts;
}
```

Post Class (stripped to basics for brevity )

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    public Post(Category category, boolean isHidden) {
        this.category = category;
        this.isHidden = isHidden
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Category category;

    private boolean isHidden;
}
```

Right now I'm doing this to filter the posts associated with categories in the CategoryController

```
@GetMapping
    public List<Category> list(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean canViewHidden = securityService.hasAuthority(Permissions.Post.VIEWHIDDEN, authentication.getAuthorities());
        List<Category> categories = categoryRepository.findAll();
        categories.forEach(
            category -> {
                Set<Post> filteredPosts = category.getPosts().stream()
                    .filter(post -> canViewHidden || !post.isHidden())
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                category.setPosts(filteredPosts);
            }
        );
        return categories;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think repositories support joins directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using a custom query in your JPA-Repository for the Post Class like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Post p INNER JOIN Category c ON p.id = c.post.id "
        + "WHERE p.hidden = false AND c.id = :id")
List<Post> findViewablePostsByCategory(@Param("id") Long categoryId);
```

I know this might not be the exact approach you were looking for but as K.Nicholas pointed out there is no way to use joins with the query building methods of JPA-Repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as I said I'm worried about being db-agnostic so I'll probably stick to the java code to filter even though it's less elegant in this instance

Comment: This isn't a native query, it's a jdbc query, meaning you can use it with any relational db.